# Set UIButton to share quick action icon

Tags: ios, swift, image, button, share

I would like to set the Quick Action share icon found at the link below to a UIButton. Is that possible? This is my code for using a custom button

```
let addButton = UIButton()
addButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Share.png"), for: .normal)
```

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/system-icons/

Comment: You can use QuickLook preview controller to preview your file (it will also add the action button) https://developer.apple.com/reference/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iOS 12 and earlier:**

We cannot load a system icon like that. However, there are several types of button types we can use to initialise to get some system icons:

- **contactAdd**
- **detailDisclosure**
- **infoDark**
- **infoLight**

Unfortunately you need to design the share icon that you need.

---

**iOS 13 and later:**

As of **iOS 13** and later, [SF Symobls](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) can be used to get a ton of system icons (over a 1000) with high quality rendering to be used in your apps.

So, the share icon you wanted can be used like so:

```
addButton.setImage(UIImage.init(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: I saw that the hierarchy didn't cross but I figured that it was worth asking. thanks

Comment: @user1079052 Just updated the answer . Just a heads up. Might be useful. You might have known it already.